# Python - printing lines from a file

Tags: python

I have a text file that contains several lines and i want to print each line. From what i know, this code should work:

```
file = open("text.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:    
    print line
file.close()
```

But it doesn't, and it gives me a syntax error..
Does anybody know why?
I tried using both IDLE and Eclipse(PyDev) and it didn't work in both.
My version of python is 3.4
Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Python 3.4, you should get `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'`. What is unclear to you about this message?

Comment: Well I thought you got it because it's the standard behavior and did not assume that you were using a probably misconfigured IDE :)

Comment: I didn't get this message. the message i got was "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 and above, [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#print) is a function not a statement (unlike in Python 2), so you need to do:

```
file = open("text.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:    
    print(line)
file.close()
```

Comment: Yes! that was the problem. thanks! Eclipse didn't point that out, it just wrote:"syntax error"..